# Trying to change colors of pixels with Mat in openCV, but somehow triples everything

Tags: opencv, image-processing, mask, pixel, mat

I'm trying to make a transparent mask that will only show moving objects on a black background. Using BakcgrounsubstractorMOG2, and by comparing the two Mat pictures for every pixel. If MOG2 has a black pixel it should make the original pixel black as well. but somehow it triples everything?
(I did not have this problem with still images using imread('blabla.JPG) )

Screenshot:

[image]

```
int main(){
    namedWindow("FG Mask MOG2");
    namedWindow("frame");`enter code here`
    pMOG2= new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();

//create the capture object
VideoCapture capture("../data/test_video.mp4");
if(!capture.isOpened()){
    //error in opening the video input
    cerr << "Unable to open video file: " << "test_video.mp4" << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
//read input data. ESC or 'q' for quitting
while( (char)keyboard != 'q' && (char)keyboard != 27 ){
    //read the current frame
    if(!capture.read(frame)) {
        cerr << "Unable to read next frame." << endl;
        cerr << "Exiting..." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pMOG2->operator()(frame, fgMaskMOG2);

    for(int y=0;y < fgMaskMOG2.rows ;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<fgMaskMOG2.cols;x++)
        {
            Vec3b color_mask = fgMaskMOG2.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y));
            Vec3b &color_frame = frame.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y));

            if(color_mask[0] <5 && color_mask[1] <5 && color_mask[2] <5)
            {
              color_frame[0] = 0; color_frame[1] = 0; color_frame[2] = 0;
            }

        }
    }

    imshow("FG Mask MOG2", fgMaskMOG2);
    imshow("frame", frame);

    keyboard = waitKey( 30 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign values to `color_frame` you either use:

```
color_frame(0) = 0
```

or:

```
color_frame.val[0] = 0
```